# SignalR not working since migrating to server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, signalr

I built a webservice that processes notification requests and a website that receives the push notifications using SignalR. This all worked fine when running both the webservice and Website on my box using Visual Studio and whatever webserver VS uses to run projects.

However since moving to a test server which runs IIS 7, the signalR no longer works. Both the webservice and website are on the same server, website on port 8088 and webservice on port 8089.

This is the error I get

```
10-12-2015 14:56:26,864 [UK\!kerslaj1][35] ERROR Centrica.CE.SEFlex.Common.Logging.ConsoleLogger - There was an error opening the connection 'http://localhost:8088/'
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.HttpClientException: StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Connection: close
  Date: Thu, 10 Dec 2015 14:56:26 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
  Content-Length: 334
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
}
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Http.DefaultHttpClient.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Get>b__1(HttpResponseMessage responseMessage)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.TaskRunners`2.<>c__DisplayClass42.<RunTask>b__41(Task`1 t)
10-12-2015 14:56:26,866 [UK\!kerslaj1][41] DEBUG Centrica.CE.SEFlex.Common.Logging.ConsoleLogger - Connection started
10-12-2015 14:56:26,866 [UK\!kerslaj1][41] DEBUG Centrica.CE.SEFlex.Common.Logging.ConsoleLogger - User: kerslaj1
10-12-2015 14:56:26,866 [UK\!kerslaj1][41] DEBUG Centrica.CE.SEFlex.Common.Logging.ConsoleLogger - Added username: UK\!kerslaj1
10-12-2015 14:56:26,867 [UK\!kerslaj1][41] ERROR Centrica.CE.SEFlex.Common.Logging.ConsoleLogger - There was an error notifying using the connection http://localhost:8088/
System.InvalidOperationException: Data cannot be sent because the connection is in the disconnected state. Call start before sending any data.
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Connection.Send(String data)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Hubs.HubProxy.Invoke[TResult,TProgress](String method, Action`1 onProgress, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Hubs.HubProxy.Invoke[T](String method, Object[] args)
   at Centrica.CE.SEFlex.Common.Notification.SignalRHandler.Notify(EventNotification notification, IEnumerable`1 subscribers, String hubConnection) in c:\Development\TFS\Atlas\SE\DEV\SEFLEX\Build\Common\Centrica.CE.SEFlex.Common\Notification\SignalRHandler.cs:line 66
10-12-2015 14:56:26,868 [UK\!kerslaj1][41] DEBUG SEFlex - Subscriber notified
```

On my website the SignalR is configured as so

```
 public class OwinStartup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();
            container.RegisterType<NotificationHub, NotificationHub>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
            GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IHubActivator), () => new UnityHubActivator(container));

            var idProvider = new PrincipalUserIdProvider();
            GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IUserIdProvider), () => idProvider);

            // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here            
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
```

And my layout html page

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/signalr")
    <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
        <script>

        var notifyProxy = $.connection.notification, // the generated client-side hub proxy
            $notificationTable = $('#NotificationTable'),
            $notificationTableBody = $notificationTable.find('tbody'),
            rowTemplate = '<tr data-symbol="{EventNotificationId}"><td style="text-align:left;width:115px;vertical-align:text-top;"><nobr>{EventDate} : </nobr></td><td><span class="{Class}"><small class="text-uppercase">{ClassLabel}</small></span></td><td style="text-align:left;">{Description}</td></tr>';

        function formatNotification(notification) {
            return $.extend(notification, {
                EventDate: notification.EventTime.substr(0, 10).concat(' ').concat(notification.EventTime.substr(11, 8)),
                Description: notification.FriendlyText,
                Class: notification.Class                
            });
        }

        function init() {
            notifyProxy.server.getCurrentNotifications().done(function (notifications) {
                $notificationTableBody.empty();
                $.each(notifications, function () {
                    var notification = formatNotification(this);
                    $notificationTableBody.prepend(rowTemplate.supplant(notification));
                });
            });
        }

        // Add a client-side hub method that the server will call
        notifyProxy.client.addNotification = function (notification) {
            $notificationTableBody.prepend(rowTemplate.supplant(formatNotification(notification)));
        };

        // Start the connection
        $.connection.hub.start().done(init);

    </script>
```

Comment: This is a bit of a stab in the dark, but could it be that it expects SignalR to be listening by default on port 80, and you're running your site on port 8088, or that SignalR is still listening on port 80 and your site is on 8088?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a stab in the dark, but could it be that it expects SignalR to be listening by default on port 80, and you're running your site on port 8088. Or that SignalR is still listening on port 80 and your site is on 8088?

Maybe setting the connection URL might do the trick?

```
$.connection.hub.url = "http://[HOST URL HERE]:8080/signalr";
```